# Crash "Activity client record must not be null to execute transaction item" only on Android 12

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics

Some week ago I noticed crashes in Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity client record must not be null to execute transaction item
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.getActivityClientRecord(ActivityTransactionItem.java:85)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.getActivityClientRecord(ActivityTransactionItem.java:58)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:43)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Seems it occurs on app start but 100% on Android 12 and 95% on samsung (75% samsung Galaxy A51) devices. I checked on A51 but for me it works fine and I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe someone already solved this issue or has some insight into what or where could be something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same crash on our application, and no idea on what triggered this from our code

Comment: I still didn't find what caused this problem or where the issue could be.

Comment: Also getting this crash quite a bit according to Crashlytics, not able to reproduce. Crashlytics says it's an early crash and it's only Android 12, so maybe something to do with the new splash screen?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a bug in Android 12 that has been fixed, but not rolled out fully yet. Ref:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210886009

You can workaround this issue by bypassing the splash screen APIs on Android 12 as show below:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var splashScreen: SplashScreen? = null
    private val shouldAvoidSplashScreen = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.S ||
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2

    private var dismissSplash = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (shouldAvoidSplashScreen) setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp) else {
            splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (shouldAvoidSplashScreen.not()) splashScreen?.run {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition { !dismissSplash }
        }
        setContent { ... }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did anyone find a fix for this? Or should we wait until everyone just updates their devices?

Comment: After a year I am facing the same issue now, has anyone found a workaround, or even what this is triggered from?

Comment: This one looks like a serious shitshow. There is a June 15, 2023 comment on that bug report suggesting it is caused be the new splashscreen API. If that's the case  the guys at Android have no clue what they are doing, scary! I mean it is not like we even needed that splashscreen API.

Comment: I implemented the workaround suggested on that bug report and it looks like that did it. Though in my case I bypassed the splashscreen API for anything below Android 13. Though I did not need to change the theme before the `super.onCreate` call. See: https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/commit/c2474a95cd543aaa888fbb6f48fa1d4ba416123e
Also edited the answer above to suggest that workaround.