# Samsung Android 12 App crash (Activity client record must not be null to execute transaction item)

Tags: android, crashlytics, samsung-mobile, illegalargumentexception, android-12

Firebase Crashlytics show multiple instances where the app crashes on particularly Samsung devices running Android 12.
Below is the observed crash :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Activity client record must not be null to execute transaction item
android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.getActivityClientRecord (ActivityTransactionItem.java:85)
```

I was able to reproduce the crash, with Samsung android 12 device.
Go to App Info -> Force Stop the app -> Launch app -> App crashes with the above exception.

I found this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210886009) which says, Samsung is rolling out a fix for this, but is there a work around to handle it on app side until all the users install the fix?

Is this triggered because of some library I have been using?

Also curious, if this is a common bug and how is everyone else handling this crash.

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/72390747/4232765)